# On a lemma of projective dimension

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings, graded-rings-modules

Let $R$ be a finite-dimensional algebra, and $A=R\oplus A_1\oplus A_2\oplus \dotsb$ be an $\mathbb{N}$-graded algebra which is locally finite (i.e. all $A_i$'s are of finite dimension). Let $\text{GrMod}A$ denote the category of graded right $A$-modules, and $\underline{\text{Ext}}$ denote the graded Ext functor. The authors [1] state the following lemma without a proof:

> **Lemma 3.2** Let $0\neq M\in\text{GrMod} A$ such that $\text{pd}_A M<\infty$. If, for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\underline{\text{Ext}}^i_A(M, A)=0$ for $i\neq n$, then $\text{pd}_A M = n$.

I'm not able to come up with a proof by myself and here's what I've tried.

Suppose $\text{pd}_AM$ is not $n$, say $m$. Then there exists a (not necessarily finitely generated) module $N$ such that $\underline{\text{Ext}}^m(M, N)\neq 0$. Let $I$ be a generator set of $N$, and we get a short exact sequence $0\to K\to A^I\to N\to 0$. Apply $\underline{\text{Ext}}$, and there is a long exact sequence $\underline{\text{Ext}}^m_A(M, A^I)\to \underline{\text{Ext}}^m_A(M, N)\to\underline{\text{Ext}}^{m_1}_A(M, K)=0$. Now it suffices to show $\underline{\text{Ext}}^m_A(M, A^I)=0$ using the fact that $\underline{\text{Ext}}^m_A(M, A)=0$, but this is where I'm stuck.

[1] *Minamoto, Hiroyuki; Mori, Izuru*, [**The structure of AS-Gorenstein algebras.**](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2010.11.004), Adv. Math. 226, No. 5, 4061-4095 (2011). [ZBL1228.16023](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1228.16023).